# Getting wrong result with Lucas probable prime test on specific composite

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, primality-test

I'm trying to do the [extra strong Lucas probable prime test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_pseudoprime#Strong_Lucas_pseudoprimes) on $15$ but keep getting the wrong result. $15=3 \cdot 5$ so it's composite, but the Lucas test says it's prime.

The parameters are $Q=1, P=15, D=221$ Since $n+1$ is a power of 2, the odd part is 1 so $s=1$. Then the condition $V_{d\cdot2^r} \equiv 0 (\bmod{n})$ for $0 \le r < s$ is true. Because with $r=0$ then $V_1=15=n$

Where is my mistake? Is $P$ wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are choosing $P$ by the method suggested on Wikipedia: set $Q=1$, and try values of $P$ starting from $3,4,5,\dots$ until $D = P^2-4$ satisfies $\left(\frac Dn\right)=-1$. Here, $P=15$ is indeed the smallest value of $P$ for which this holds.

Part of the fine print (which Wikipedia doesn't mention, but which is included in the [Mathematica code](https://oeis.org/A217719/a217719.txt) for [OEIS sequence A217719](https://oeis.org/A217719), the list of extra strong Lucas pseudoprimes) is that when $\left(\frac Dn\right)=0$ (that is, when $\gcd(D,n) > 1$) we should also stop, except in the unusual case that $D=n$ which comes up only for $n=5$. At this point, we know that $n$ is composite, for example because $\gcd(D,n)$ is a nontrivial divisor of $n$ (but see the note at the bottom of this answer).

There's some other fine print, too: when $n$ is even, or when $n$ is a perfect square, we treat that as a special case, declare $n$ to be composite, and stop.

In real-life examples, this situation is basically never going to come up, because it happens when we randomly stumble on a nontrivial divisor of $n$, so it's extremely unlikely to happen when $n$ is not obviously composite. But it is an exceptional case that needs to be dealt with, and if you're testing the algorithm on small numbers, you'll see it often.

In particular, when we take $n=15$, we first try $P=3$ and get $D = P^2-4 = 5$; since $\gcd(D,n)>1$, we stop and conclude that $n$ is composite.

---

Why the "only $n=5$" detail above? Well, the case that $\left(\frac Dn\right) = 0$ can come up in two ways.

- It happens if $n \mid D$, or $P^2-4 \equiv 0 \pmod n$. This definitely happens when we reach $P=n-2$, but we should find a good $D$ before that happens except in the unusual case $n=5$. If it happens for $P<n-2$, then $\gcd(P+2,n)$ and $\gcd(P-2,n)$ are nontrivial divisors of $n$, and $n$ is composite.
- It happens when $1 < \gcd(n,D) < n$. This only happens for composite $D$. In this case, $\gcd(n,D)$ is a nontrivial factor of $n$.

So either way, for $n>5$, when we see $\left( \frac Dn\right)=0$, we stop.

Comment: Wikipedia states "It is a good idea to check that n has no prime factors in common with P or Q". Do you know if this is still true for the extra strong version of the test? For extra strong $Q=1$ so it wouldn't make sense to check it...

Comment: Also is it necessary for check if GCD(D,n)>1 in the strong version? I have tested it out and it doesn't seem to but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_pseudoprime#Strong_Lucas_pseudoprimes) may  suggest it "for a given (P, Q) pair [a strong Lucas pseudoprime] is an odd composite number n with GCD(n, D) = 1"

Comment: For the second question, we will always compute the Jacobi symbol $\left(\frac Dn\right)$, which is implemented as a fancier GCD computation, and if $\left(\frac Dn\right) = 0$, then that implies $\gcd(n,D) > 1$ - so we don't need to check that separately.

Comment: For the first question: assume $n$ is odd and $\left(\frac Dn\right)=-1$. We need $\gcd(n,Q)=1$ for the congruence $U_{n+1}\equiv 0\pmod n$ to hold, so we would usually check for that, but it's free in the extra strong case, when $Q=1$. There are three other checks that can be done (see equations (2)-(4) in the [Lucas pseudoprimes paper](http://mpqs.free.fr/LucasPseudoprimes.pdf)): $V_{n+1} \equiv 2Q\pmod n$, $U_n \equiv -1 \pmod n$, $V_n \equiv P \pmod n$. Under the further assumption that $\gcd(n,P)=1$, any of these conditions implies the others, which is the advantage of checking that gcd.

Comment: I guess none of those are particularly reasons to check $\gcd(n,P)$ or $\gcd(n,Q)$, just things that affect the answer; they're not going to mess up the test.

Comment: I asked another question about Lucas sequences and primality testing here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3637889/how-to-find-first-term-in-sequence-for-lucas-lehmer-riesel-test